# why prefix "<any>" before window object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript, I saw a book that has below statement:

```
(<any>window).model= ...;
```

I'm confused, what's the name of syntax by adding `<any>` before a variable and what's the benefits doing that?

Comment: If you're new to typescript, I recommend not using it. Instead learn everything you can about [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). These type assertions are a waste of time. They solve a problem that's really not a problem at all for me.

Comment: @LonnieBest I personally also not recommend use typescript, but why you mention modules? It's totally unrelated.

Comment: @LonnieBest "If you're new to programming, I recommend not doing it. Instead learn everything you can about cooking because programming is a waste of time." bit of a weird argument not to use something just because you're new to it. If you don't see the advantages of it then you're doing it wrong. TypeScript is a massive time saver because you can catch incorrectly written code while you're typing it instead of sometime later down the line at runtime.

Comment: @appleapple : When typescript came out in 2014, the most significant benefit it offered was a methodology for managing large projects. Now, though, native Javascript Modules are in the standard, and with them you can manage a project of any size.

Comment: @LonnieBest Oh, I don't know that, if so, then you have a fair point.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz You can also say *If you don't see the advantages of vanilla javascript then you're doing it wrong.* well, you didn't make valid argument either. (to be clear, I just think it's personal choice)

Comment: @appleapple There are no clear advantages of vanilla over TypeScript in my opinion. Also if he's using Angular for example it's not really viable to say "don't use TypeScript".. Sure you can deviate from it but it would be more difficult than just learning TypeScript.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz : For catching problems while I type, I use [eslint](https://eslint.org/). The kind of problems that typescript's type assertions catch are so obvious that it is not worth the time "adding assertions to everything" just to catch such easily solvable errors. You'll save more time by NOT asserting than you'll gain from it catching those errors real-time. Personally, I don't need those training wheels on my bicycle.

Comment: @LonnieBest It might not be obvious to the person sitting next to you at work. Just because you don't need something doesn't mean everyone else don't need it either. I've had horrible experiences with eslint and would therefore not use it over TypeScript. So yeah, personal preference I guess.

Answer (score 1):

That is a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). You are telling the compiler to use a different type then the one it thinks it is.

Answer (score 0):

When using type assertion like that you're basically telling the compiler "Hey compiler I know what I'm doing, relax.". Sometimes you have to do this in order to be able to set new properties on an object for example, I would assume that if you just did `window.model` the compiler would complain, saying `model` is not a property of `window`.

It's only recommended to do this when you really have to, using `any` for everything is the same as not using TypeScript at all. So use caution whenever you decide to assert a type.

Bonus info:

You can also write `window as any`, in my opinion it is slightly more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Because `model` doesn't exists in Window interface:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.4/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18500

You can access `window.document`, `window.addEventListener()`, etc.

So, you are telling the compiler "let window object to be **any**thing".

Without the cast  the compiler says `Property 'model' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.`

Another example:

```
interface Person {
    age: number;
    name: string
}

let michael: Person = {
   age: 28,
   name: 'Michael'
};

michael.age++;
(<any>michael).hasDogs = true; // hasDogs is not a property of Person, so cast michael to be anything
```

You can test it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/O4SwdgJg9sB0C2UIFMA2ACAvOg5ACzVRhwG4g